# "Your network preferences prevent content from being loaded remotely" in Mail app does not go away

Tags: mail.app, monterey

This started happening after the update to Monterey. I tried doing [as suggested here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253327312):

> Open Mail. Then goto the menu bar and click on  Mail, then go down to
> Preferences. Then in the preferences pop up box, at the far right
> click on Privacy. You will probably find either Protect Mail Activity
> checked or Block All Remote Content. If either of them are checked
> images will be blocked and you get the Load Remote Content box at the
> top of any mail with an image. I am not sure if only having Hide IP
> address does also. Uncheck all or any of them and you should get
> images loaded in each mail.

but I still have the same problem. "Protect Mail Activity" and "Load Remote Content" are both unchecked in Mail preferences.

Anyone have any idea what could be going on?

Comment: Is "Limit IP Address Tracking" in System Preferences > Network enabled (see https://help.nextdns.io/t/q6hpbh0?r=83hb4nr)?

Comment: @jaume hmm, yes, and deselecting it solves the problem. However, will this compromise security in any way?

Comment: It won't compromise security, but macOS won't be able to hide your online activity from known trackers. So it seems the remote content that's not being loaded is in fact used to track you. It's a trade-off, and a decision for you to make...